# RxJS- Angular2 - Conditional stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

New to RxJS, using Angular2 & @ngrx/store & /effects.

I'm trying to work out how to make a stream that handles a conditional result from a service... this is to work out if a user is logged in or not when the app first runs by checking if auth credentials are stored in LocalStorage.

This may be the completely wrong way to deal with this so any advice appreciated.

At the moment I have an effect

```
  @Effect() check$ = this.updates$
.whenAction(AuthActions.AUTHENTICATE_CHECK)
.map(update => this.authService.checkAuth())
// now what?  
// returns an observable of false, or a Auth object if LS info found
// needs to return  
// this.authActions.authenticateCheckResult(res) if ok and
//  this.authActions.authenticateCheckError() if not ok
```

And the `checkAuth` method in the `authService` is like this...

```
checkAuth():Observable {
 this._user = <AuthAPI>this.ls.getObject(AuthService.LS_AUTH_KEY);

 if(this._user && this._user.accessToken) {
   return Observable.of(this._user);
 }
 else {
   return Observable.of(false);
 }
}
```

---

**Update**

I have it working doing this...

```
  @Effect() check$ = this.updates$
.whenAction(AuthActions.AUTHENTICATE_CHECK)
.map(update => this.authService.checkAuth())
.map(result => {
  if(!result) {
    return this.authActions.authenticateCheckError(false);
  } else {
    return this.authActions.authenticateCheckSuccess(result)
  }
});
```

//

```
checkAuth():AuthAPI {
this._user = <AuthAPI>this.ls.getObject(AuthService.LS_AUTH_KEY);

if(this._user && this._user.accessToken) {
  return this._user;
}
else {
  return null;
}
```

}

Is this a valid way of doing this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain your calls like

```
checkAuth():Observable<AuthAPI> {
    return Rx.Observable.of(<AuthAPI>this.ls.getObject(AuthService.LS_AUTH_KEY))
                        .filter(user => user)
                        .filter(user.accessToken)
                        .defaultIfEmpty(null)
```